# How to convert to HTML code?

Tags: command-line, character-encoding, conversion, html

Are there any scripts that can convert between text (e.g. `<hi>`) and the html entities version (`&lt;hi&gt;`) like [this website](http://centricle.com/tools/html-entities/) does? Or at least a PHP file?

Comment: I'm not sure what "html entities version" means. Can you elaborate on how this differs from regular html conversioni? If you just want a text to html coverter, a quick search shows http://txt2html.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The perl CGI module has a `escapeHTML` function that makes it pretty easy:

```
perl -e 'use CGI qw(escapeHTML); print escapeHTML("<hi>\n");'
```

Or to do an entire file:

```
perl -p -e 'BEGIN { use CGI qw(escapeHTML); } $_ = escapeHTML($_);'  FILENAME
```

Answer (score 3):

The [recode](http://www.gnu.org/software/recode/) utility supports HTML as one of the encodings. (You can even specify an HTML version.) In the text-to-entities direction, it will also recode non-ASCII characters into entities; you need to specify the correct input encoding (e.g. ASCII, latin1, utf-8, …).

```
recode utf8:html <input-file.txt >output-file.txt
recode l1..html file-to-recode.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`xmlstarlet` can do it both ways:

```
echo '<em>Ampersands & angle brackets need to be encoded.</em>' |
xmlstarlet esc | 
xmlstarlet unesc
```

Comment: That fails to encode the &. If just esc is used then all the less than and greater than characters are also encoded as &lt; &gt;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your original goal/purpose, but if you are wanting to show PHP source to someone --

You can rename the file to *.phps extension and (in many Apache/PHP configurations, but not all) it will not parse the PHP when serving the file to the user; it will show the source directly.

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants; he wants either a command-line tool or a PHP script that will take text input and escape HTML entities

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested: I wrote a well documented easily readable open-source bash script that converts accented letters in HTML entities. You can find it here:
http://www.lugato.co.uk/silvio_dwl.html
It is easy to understand so it can be easily modified to convert additional characters in HTML entities ;)
Enjoy it!
Silvio

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.